# Flight Ticket Cancellation

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I need to buy a flight ticket for my Schengen Visa application. But for some reason I want to change my flight ticket without any additional fee. That said, I need a refundable flight ticket. My choice of airlines are Lufthansa or Turkish. I may consider other European airlines as well. Which airline would be the best for me? Also, is there anything that I need to pay extra attention to when I buy my ticket?

Comment: You don't have to buy your air tickets before you apply for a visa. It is sufficient to submit an itinerary. Refundable tickets are much more expensive than non-refundable tickets.

Comment: What does confirmed flight reservation mean? That's what Swiss consulate needs for tourism visa.

Comment: A trick, if you can immobilise some money, is to buy a refundable ticket that you will use just to be refunded. With Lufthansa for example, refundable tickets can be refunded without any fee and you can cancel it easily via a web page. You will miss maybe 2000 euros for a while though, so it might not be very convenient.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi did you find any flight with free cancellation? I am looking for the same thing for the purpose of Schengen Visa application. Thanks

Comment: @sky-light I didn't book (pay). You can reserve flights online with Turkish airline which gives you few days to pay. However, you don't have to book and there won't be any penalty. I think this is basically what the consulate needs and not the actual ticket. I think they call it a confirmed reservation.

Answer (score 2):

Airlines have unfortunately a lot of fare different classes which makes this complicated and confusing. You need to check prices and policies individually. Typically a refundable is about twice as much as a discounted ticket, and most airlines will let you change the cheap ticket for a fee of $100-$300. It also depends on what you change: a simple date change is easier to negotiate than a route change. A route change may also incur a fee on a refundable ticket as well.